# Как получить текст из GET запросa?

Tags: javascript

Я не сильно разбираюсь в JavaScript,но должно выглядеть как то так.

1) идёт GET запрос

2) получаю ответ

3) фильтрую тэги и получаю текст,но выдаёт ошибку 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null' (от переменной c)

P.S. Ответ идёт то,что надо,но не фильтруется переменной c.

Код JS:

```
var c = document.querySelector('div[class="entry"]').textContent;
var b = document.querySelector('div[style="top: 42px; width: 690px; padding: 0px 20px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: absolute; text-align: center; font: 32px/32px Arial;"]').textContent
var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
a.open("GET", "https://site.com/?s=" + encodeURIComponent(b), true);
a.onload = function (){
    alert(c);
}
a.send(null);
```

Comment: А почему именно такая выборка?
var b = document.querySelector('div[style="top: 42px; width: 690px; padding: 0px 20px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: absolute; text-align: center; font: 32px/32px Arial;"]').textContent

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить текст из GET запроса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899668/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0)

Comment: @doox911 потому что на странице много div style,пришлось делать так.

Comment: @kazio используйте классы. Для ajax лучше использовать jquery или любой framework, например Vue.

Comment: @doox911 ?,Я не сильно разбираюсь в js,можно пример?

Comment: Вам в прошлом вопросе уже ответили - у вас нет на странице элемента с селектором `div[class="entry"]`!

Comment: @stepan-kasyanenko даладно? я знаю... Мне бы ответ как это справить.

Comment: Представьте себе! Ответ как это исправить очень прост - создайте элемент с таким селектором в `html`! А если серьезно, то что бы ответить нужен рабочий пример с `html`, `css` и `js`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko и как я его могу сделать?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko не ну я могу залить html файл на сервер,http://o96618y9.beget.tech/index.html ,и запустите chrome с параметрами --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=c:\foo

Comment: Нет, спасибо, я не буду запускать хром с такими параметрами. Сделайте пример кода здесь, в песочнице. Можете добавить пример вашего кода в сниппет.

Answer (score 1):

Например ваш код можно реализовать так (при помощи [JQuery](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC_GET)):

```
let a = $('div.entry).text(), 
    b = $('div.myclass).text();
    url = "https://site.com/?s="+b;
$.get(url,function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

переменную **b** необходимо будет очистить (например от пробелов).